# Why pipe not working on the vue.js version 2.1.6?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I use vue js version 2.1.6

My vue component like this :

```
<div id="app">
    <h1>Simple typeahead example</h1>
    <input placeholder="Search US states" @input="input" v-model="typeahead" />
    <ul v-if="!selected && typeahead">
      <li v-for="state in states | filterBy typeahead" @click="select(state)">{{ state }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My full code on the jsfiddle like this : http://jsfiddle.net/tm8k8907/12/

If the code executed, there exist error like this :

```
invalid expression: v-for="state in states | filterBy typeahead"
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Vue 2 [removed filters outside text interpolations](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Filters-Outside-Text-Interpolations-removed). You should use a computed property as covered in the linked documentation. Here is your [fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/tm8k8907/15/).

Comment: @Bert, Thanks a lot. It works